# Set up multicast in MikroTik router and in PC

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, windows-firewall, multicast, mikrotik-routeros

My internet provider broadcasts several TV channels over multicast on port 5004. They provided me with these instructions for enabling receiving of their multicast broadcast:

> In your case it is fully sufficient if your router supports IGMP / Multicast Filter feature, multicast is broadcasted over port 5004.
>
> In the PC, you need to set an exception in the firewall for VLC media player.

What I did so far:

1. I installed PIM package into MikroTik router **RB951G-2HnD** and checked that it is prepared. I can also see it logging. I read router documentation and some forums on multicast topic.
2. In DYI attempt, I set firewall exception (incoming UDP) for VLC Player and "somehow" configured the first tab in PIM module and tried to open list of channels in VLC media player by clicking **Network streams (SAP)** in left panel. But it did not work. Was I missing Rendezvous Point setting? (at RP tab)

Could please someone let me know how to set up MikroTik router to allow multicast? I see tabs **Interface** and **RP** (Rendezvous Points) but I don't know how added records should look like.

Comment: Please provide the full address you’re trying to “connect” to. Are you sure your ISP doesn’t have a split setup like Deutsche Telekom, where IPTV is sent over a different DSL channel?

Comment: @DanielB – do you need the full address to test the connection by yourself? From what I know, I'm afraid the address is blocked to be accessible only to clients connected into provider's networks, it is unreachable when connected through another provider. The provider is *antik.sk*, their infrastructure is based only on optical fibres 1Gb/s per endpoint (and outside the city wireless point-to-point 16Mb/s), they don't use DSL.

Comment: No, it’s to verify it is actually a multicast address. I agree, it’s most likely in the non-global multicast range. I’m somewhat familiar with the Deutsche Telekom IPTV system.

Comment: @DanielB – I can confirm the address falls into multicast address range 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255.

Comment: Run a packet capture on your router and verify it actually subscribes to the multicast group. You can filter for IGMP when capturing.